# SwiftUI nested ForEach

Tags: swiftui

I have a horizontal scrollview with 11 cards, that contains an image and a text, the texts works just fine with the forEach loop

[image]

```
struct HorizontalScrollView: View {
    
    var model = VerticalScrollModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color.purple)
            ScrollView (.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack (spacing: -15) {
                    let name: [String] = model.textCardsContent
                    let images: [String] = model.imagesCardsContent
                    
                    ForEach(name, id: \.self) { name in
                        ForEach(images, id: \.self) { images in
                            ScrollViewContentCard(contentText: name, contentImages: images)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.purple)
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
    }
}

struct HorizontalScrollView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HorizontalScrollView()
    }
}
```

but when I put another foreach nested inside to load images, things goes south, my ordered scroll becomes unordered, here is my model struct that I am using to load the strings.

```
struct VerticalScrollModel {
    
    var textCardsContent = ["Pix", "Pagar", "indicar\namigos", "trasferir", "Depositar", "Empréstimos", "Cartão virtual", "Recarga de\ncelular", "Ajustar\nlimite", "Bloquear\ncartão", "cobrar", "Doação", "Me ajuda"]
    var imagesCardsContent = ["pix", "reward", "loan"]
    
}
```

also my scrollcontentview the way I layout

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollViewContentCard: View {
    
    var contentText: String
    var contentImages: String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color.purple)
                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5).stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 1.5))
            VStack (spacing: 20) {
                Image(contentImages)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    .padding(.top)
                Text(contentText)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 12))
                    .frame(height: 40)
            }
            .padding(.leading, 1)
        }
        .frame(width: 100, height: 95)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ScrollViewContentCard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ScrollViewContentCard(contentText: "Indicar amigos", contentImages: "pix")
    }
}
```

as am example the card below is what I wanna do 12 of then with different images and texts, thanks in advance

[image: demo1]

Comment: Your code shows only one ForEach. Can you post unedited full code? Please include specific output that is unordered and ordered. A ForEach will not change the order of an array, so your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Ryan, I have posted with the two loops, is all that code that i have

Comment: Can you post the results observed and the results you expected?

Comment: I just shared pictures o the app scrollview that I am trying to emulate, an how mine clone is presenting the scroll information

Comment: Your question / problem is "when I put another foreach nested inside to load images, things goes south, my ordered scroll becomes unordered...". The screenshot is pretty, but irrelevant. What do you mean by unordered? The ForEach will take the first element of the outer array and apply the inner ForEach, then take the next element in the outer array and do the same.

Comment: I found a solution here, appreciate